# Access level / security roles design choice: individual roles or inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, design-patterns, cancan

Please consider this scenario: a web app that has 4 levels of access: admin > manager > representative > customer > no role (public access pages)

With my current app setup I can allow access in 2 ways:

1. I can write code, that will assume role precedence, i.e. if a user is a a manager - app will automatically assume that he/she has the right to access areas that customer & representative can, but not the admin.
2. I can assign each role individually in a table. For instance a user  will have 3 roles assigned to them. So the app will not assume role precedence / inheritance. I can either let the admin assign users with roles, or right some code that will automatically assign extra roles to a user if a higher access level is granted.

Which of this two approaches is better from the standpoint of maintainability?

P.S.

I don't think this matters but I'm using Rails 3 with CanCan & Devise. 
Also my setup for the relationship between roles and users is the following:

Role <=> (HABTM) <=> User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar role requirement and I've chosen approach 1. It's natural to assume that the higher up the role hierarchy you go, the more access you have. So, saying a manager has access to the resources a representative has is OK.

Also, since you're using CanCan, the fall through is very easily set up. Start with the role with the least access at the top of the initialize block and work your way down.

Comment: Srdjan, thanks for your reply. Follow up question: what if the name of the role changes or I have to add more granular role support. What I mean - there is no single vertical inheritance anymore. I.E.: I want to grant some representatives, new role called product_manager, and give some others faq_manager, yet another rep should be able to news_manager.  How would do you handle cases like this? In the past - I used second approach and it worked out ok. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, if you need a more granularity and roles don't necessarily build on each other, I'd also go with approach 2. The beauty of cancan is that you can do either, if you need it to.